# SQL full join without any conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using MS SQL.
I have the following tables:

```
table A:
    id1   data1
    8234    ko
    2       po
    333     koo
    40      woo

table B:
    id2     data2
    123     meow
    654     frrr

table C:
    id3     data3
    10          a
    20          b
    30          c
    40          d
    50          e   
    60          f
```

I want to get this:

```
    id1     data1       id2     data2       id3     data3
    8234    ko          123      meow        10         a
    2       po          654      frrr        20         b
    333     koo         NULL     NULL        30         c
    40      woo         NULL     NULL        40         d
    NULL    NULL        NULL     NULL        50         e
    NULL    NULL        NULL     NULL        60         f
```

It's seems like full sum of tables without any conditions. I just want to get all columns and all data from all tables as is.
How can I do this?
UPD: tables are not related. 
In case when tables are related: I would use LEFT or RIGHT JOIN, when it was known in advance what table is larger than. But it is unknown.

Comment: Are these tables related at all?

Comment: @Ploutox, FULL JOIN requires a condition for join, isn't it?

Comment: Since there's no relationship between the tables, this smacks of a display hack - are you sure this needs doing down in the database, and not instead up at some layer that's actually concerned with presentation?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I have no power over the database. I just need to get some data out.

Comment: Read  @Damien_The_Unbeliever's comment again. Do you really need the table data side by side as shown? You can get "all data from all tables" via three queries. (Or by extending each table's rows by anything in the others' columns then UNIONing.)

Comment: 1. OUTER JOIN (all kinds) SQL syntax requires an ON condition but as operators OUTER JOINs do not require a condition, ie the condition can be true, ie SQL syntax ON 1=1. Of course, in that case it returns the CROSS JOIN since every input row is matched by the condition. 2. But the output you want doesn't involve OUTER JOINs ON the data, as you claim in your question, only (as the accepted answer shows) FULL JOIN ON surrogates (a value for each output line) that just drag their data along with them.

Comment: @philipxy, the reason was in awful report builder. So, yes. I had to do such things inside SQL query.

Comment: (Re my earlier comment:) "in that case it returns the CROSS JOIN"--unless exactly one table is empty. "as operators OUTER JOINs do not require a condition"--in that they have "natural" versions which for no common columns act like ON TRUE.

Comment: @philipxy nice addition after 5 years ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM A
    FULL OUTER JOIN B ON 1 = 1
    FULL OUTER JOIN C ON 1 = 1
```

Answer (score 10):

Create an index using `row_number` to use for your full join

```
select * from (
    select 
        row_number() over (order by id1 asc) rn,
        id1, data1
    from ta
) t1    
full join (
    select 
        row_number() over (order by id2 asc) rn,
        id2, data2
    from tb
) t2 on t1.rn = t2.rn
full join (
    select 
        row_number() over (order by id3 asc) rn,
        id3, data3
    from tc
) t3 on t1.rn = t3.rn
```

Comment: id1 like '1,2,3' was just for example. I have edited the post now. Unfortunatly, your solution doesn't work even with example, because first table lesser than third and I will lost 2 strings from third table. :(

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
with a as
(select *, row_number() over (order by id1) an from tableA),
b as
(select *, row_number() over (order by id2) bn from tableB),
c as
(select *, row_number() over (order by id3) cn from tableC)

select a.id1, a.data1, b.id2, b.data2, c.id3, c.data3 
from a
full outer join b on a.an = b.bn
full outer join c on a.an = c.cn
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/44004/10)

Answer (score -3):

I think it's impossible to join tables without matching any conditions. Otherwise, you have to put the key from table B with one of table A key. It doesn't matter if you don't want to put the table B key(matched with table A key). You're still able to join it, using SQL query.

It will be like:

```
SELECT tableA.*, tableB.* FROMtableA JOIN tableB ON tableA.id1 = tableB.id1
```

see, you can select the field based on you want.

Comment: Except there's no universal `id` to pull.  You _can_ do thing like `CROSS JOIN`, which doesn't need conditions, but this will instead join all rows together, multiple times (instead of each row only showing up once).